# Using SonarQube GitHub Authentication Plugin results in "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Tags: github, sonarqube

In connection with setting up SonarQube, I have installed and configured GitHub Authentication plugin, to allow users to use their GitHub credentials. Now when trying to login with a GitHub account (Pressing the "Login with GitHub" button, SonarQube redirects to "https://servername/login/oauth/authorize?..." which results in an error page, stating "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.".

It seems that the correct path should be 
"https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?...", instead of pointing to my SonarQube server. Could it be that the plugin fails to resolve the URL for GitHub and using a blank url instead? Thereby creating a link to "/login/oauth/authorize?..."?

I have checked both the properties table in the database and the configurationfile for the property "sonar.auth.github.webUrl" - both are set to "https//github.com"

Comment: It seems that you are using Github Entreprise. Are you sure you have correctly configured the sonar.auth.github.apiUrl and sonar.auth.github.webUrl properties ?

Comment: Hi Julien, we're not using GitHub Enterprise. The "servername" above refers to my SonarQube server. I have added some more information about the matter. First I tried to configure the plugin thru the config file, but it didn't pick up my ClientID and Secret. Therefor I went thru the admin page and entered the settings there instead.

Comment: If you're not using GitHub Entreprise, you should remove values of sonar.auth.github.apiUrl and sonar.auth.github.webUrl. Then, which version of GitHub Auth plugin are you using ?

Comment: Ok - I'll try that. Im on version 1.3.

Comment: I now cleared sonar.auth.github.apiUrl and sonar.auth.github.webUrl thru the admin ui and in the config file, but the problem is still the same. I verified that theres no property in the database for sonar.auth.github.webUrl, i.e. select * from properties where prop_key = 'sonar.auth.github.webUrl' doesn't return anything. And the same property is commented out in the config file, whereafter I have restarted SonarQube.

Comment: This issue is very strange... Are you using a proxy or something like that ?

Comment: Nope I'm not using a proxy - my quess is that the plugin for some reason thinks that the property has been defined and uses a empty string for the Url, which results in a link to the SonarQube server. But I just cant figure out why this is.

Comment: Can you try to execute "http://servername/api/properties/sonar.auth.github.webUrl" and check that nothing is returned ?
Can you also verify that sonar.auth.github.webUrl doesn't exist in sonar.properties ?

Comment: I executed the REST API and it returned nothing. However if I execute with another property, like sonar.jdbc.username which Sonar must resolve correctly as it successfully logges on to the DB, that also returns nothing. I have checked the sonar.properties, and the line is commented out in that file. Going crazy here - really really strange ...

Comment: The "sonar.jdbc.username" is a system property, so it's normal that it's not returned by the WS. You should try for instance with "sonar.technicalDebt.hoursInDay".
No idea what is going wrong... BTW, which version of SonarQube are you using ?

Comment: I'm on version 6.0. I tried sonar.technicalDebt.hoursInDay and it returned with a correct json response (value: 8)

Comment: Hi Julien, I'm afraid that I have mislead you, when you asked if I used a proxy. I use IIS to access SonarQube via HTTPS and. I configured IIS to add X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https" to the header. Playing arround, I found that running from the box, using http://localhost:9000 worked fine - but coming from the outside, over HTTPS, it fails as described above. Any hints?

Comment: Then you'll need to check the configuration of IIS. I don't know it so unfortunately I won't be able to help you...

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for you help anyway. /Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling with this issue for some weeks now, I identified the problem and found the solution. The problem was with redirects, which due to my Reverse proxy setup, didn't work. I had followed the instructions for setting up the proxy, however it still failed. The solution was found on MSDN, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/06/04/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy/, which included a small addition to the sonarqube instructions, as it beside from the inbound rewrite rule, also included an outbound rule.